# magento 2 rating collection by review id?

Tags: magento2, ratings, product-review

Magento 2 how to get the data from **'rating_option_vote'** by **review_id** using objectmanager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use '**Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\Collection**'. Find the code for getting the collection and filtering it by **'review_id'.**

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;  
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';  
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);  
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();  
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');  
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');  

$reviewId = 5; //custom review id.  
$ratingCollection = $obj->get('Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\Collection')->addRatingInfo()->addOptionInfo()->addRatingOptions()->addFieldToFilter('review_id',$reviewId);  
print_r($ratingCollection->getData());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @venkatesankrish let me check and update you.